# Myspace developer api: No access / verify email

Tags: api, email, verify, myspace

I want to get access to the myspace api – but I can’t even access the developer platform to create an app or get my keys.

I always get this message:

We're sorry, but you must verify your email address first! You cannot access many MySpace features until you complete this step. Please return to your MySpace profile and click the "Verify your email address" link.
When this step is complete, you can re-apply to the developer platform.
I have verify my email – so I don’t know what to do to get access.

I clicked on the link in the email I get after the registration. But I didn't find another link - and I still get the same message.

Please help me!

Best regards,

Timo

Answer (score 0):

As I know MySpace developer API dead. They changed their policy fundamentally. To be more exact I say Newscorps version of Myspace is dead. A new platform solely focused on Music and a Music Streaming service.