# Create a MySpace API - (verify your email error)

Tags: api, myspace, social-media

I am trying to create a MySpace API so that my users can connect to my site using MySpace.

All the tutorials say "go to http://developer.myspace.com/ and create a developer account..."

I signed up for a new MySpace account, verified my email, gave them access to my gmail so they could search for friends, invited a few friends, basically completed all the steps they ask you too as a new user...

But whenever I go over to http://developer.myspace.com/ and click "**Developer Sign Up**" or "**Start building!**" I receive an error message that says:

> We're sorry, but you must verify your email address first! You cannot access many MySpace features until you complete this step. Please return to your MySpace profile and click the "Verify your email address" link. When this step is complete, you can re-apply to the developer platform.

I have verified my account 3 times using the link in the email they sent me, and waited 24 hours for any changes to be applied. There is no "Verify your email address" link on your profile page, so this appears to be a deprecated error message.

A bit of digging around shows this problem has existed since at least 2 years:
http://developer.myspace.com/community/forums/t/9579.aspx?PageIndex=1
... and has even been posted on here, without resolution: [Myspace developer api: No access / verify email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510719/myspace-developer-api-no-access-verify-email)

Any ideas how to get access to my API key?

Do I just have to wait for my account to show as verified...? (It's been 24 hrs already)