# MySpace Integration, Api key generate

Tags: android, myspace, api-key

I am trying to generate MySpace APi key using following link,

http://developer.myspace.com/

But whenever I go over to developer acount and click "Developer Sign Up" or "Start building!" I recieve an error message that says:

> We're sorry, but you must verify your email address first! You cannot
>   access many MySpace features until you complete this step. Please
>   return to your MySpace profile and click the "Verify your email
>   address" link. When this step is complete, you can re-apply to the
>   developer platform.

Same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103205/create-a-myspace-api-verify-your-email-error), but none could give answer.

I am using following myspace sdk,

http://myspace-android-sdk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Awaiting eagerly,
Thanks in advance...

Comment: There might be some problem from the server side right now..

Comment: You could mail MySpace? It's their API.

Answer (score 1):

Did you solve this yet? Same thing happened for me but all I had to do was retrieve my email archives and search for "myspace API", then click on the validation URL that they sent you when you signed up. It might have gotten spam filtered as well, depending on your privacy settings. If that's the case, then try to signup again using the same address, or login and look for a link that says "Forgotten Password" it might prompt them to re-send the activation link.

Failing those, your only two other options are to signup again using a completely new email address and account (but remember to go directly to your email account you sign up with this time; also possibly reduce the strictness of your spam filter temporarily until you get the email), or, send an email to MySpace tech support: DeveloperRelations@myspace-inc.com

Comment: Did you try making a new account using a different email address?

Comment: Actually, you are right there seems to be a larger problem as I could not create a new developer account. You should definitely email them in that case at the address I provided above and let them know there is a problem with the Sign Up link on the Developer Portal. I could login to my existing account though and see my apps: http://developer.myspace.com/Apps.mvc